# SQL Customized search with special characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a key-wording module where I want to search data using the comma separated words.And the search is categorized into comma `,` and minus `-`.
I know a relational database engine is designed from the principle that a cell holds a single value and obeying to this rule can help for performance.But in this case table is already running and have millions of data and can't change the table structure.

Take a look on the example what I exactly want to do is

I have a main table name `tbl_main` in SQL

```
AS_ID   KWD
1   Man,Businessman,Business,Office,confidence,arms crossed
2   Man,Businessman,Business,Office,laptop,corridor,waiting
3   man,business,mobile phone,mobile,phone
4   Welcome,girl,Greeting,beautiful,bride,celebration,wedding,woman,happiness
5   beautiful,bride,wedding,woman,girl,happiness,mobile phone,talking
6   woman,girl,Digital Tablet,working,sitting,online
7   woman,girl,Digital Tablet,working,smiling,happiness,hand on chin
```

> If  search text is =  Man,Businessman then result AS_ID is =1,2
>
> If  search text is =  Man,-Businessman then result AS_ID is =3
>
> If  search text is =  woman,girl,-Working then result AS_ID is =4,5
>
> If  search text is =  woman,girl then result AS_ID is =4,5,6,7

What is the best why to do this, Help is much appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a task for the [Full Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you elaborate more by providing explanations in each of your examples?

Comment: @wewesthemenace Yes !! Sure will Update within 5 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt using Jeff Moden's [**DelimitedSplit8k**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) to split the comma-separated values.

First, here is the splitter function *(check the article for updates of the script)*:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](
    @pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,cteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString), 0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)
,cteStart(N1) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString, t.N, 1) = @pDelimiter
),
cteLen(N1, L1) AS(
SELECT 
    s.N1,
    ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString, s.N1),0) - s.N1, 8000)
FROM cteStart s
)
SELECT 
    ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
    Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l
```

Here is the complete solution:

```
-- search parameter
DECLARE @search_text VARCHAR(8000) = 'woman,girl,-working'

-- split comma-separated search parameters
-- items starting in '-' will have a value of 1 for exclude
DECLARE @search_values TABLE(ItemNumber INT, Item VARCHAR(8000), Exclude BIT)
INSERT INTO @search_values
SELECT 
    ItemNumber, 
    CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) LIKE '-%' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(STUFF(Item, 1, 1 ,''))) ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) END,
    CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(Item)) LIKE '-%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@search_text, ',') s

;WITH CteSplitted AS( -- split each KWD to separate rows
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_main t
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT
            ItemNumber, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(Item))
        FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.KWD, ',')
    )x  
)
SELECT 
    cs.AS_ID
FROM CteSplitted cs
INNER JOIN @search_values sv
    ON sv.Item = cs.Item
GROUP BY cs.AS_ID
HAVING
    -- all parameters should be included (Relational Division with no Remainder)
    COUNT(DISTINCT cs.Item)  = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Item) FROM @search_values WHERE Exclude = 0)
    -- no exclude parameters
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN sv.Exclude = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5269c2/1/0)

This one uses a solution from the **Relational Division with no Remainder** problem discussed in this [**article**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/) by Dwain Camps.

Comment: Wow !! That is what I looking for :D a big thank to you ..Really appreciate your answer :) @wewesthemenace

Answer (score 3):

I think you can easily solve this by creating a FULL TEXT INDEX on your `KWD` column. Then you can use the [CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) query to search for phrases. The FULL TEXT index takes care of the punctuation and ignores the commas automatically.

```
-- If search text is = Man,Businessman then the query will be
SELECT AS_ID FROM tbl_main
WHERE CONTAINS(KWD, '"Man" AND "Businessman"')

-- If search text is = Man,-Businessman then  the query will be
SELECT AS_ID FROM tbl_main
WHERE CONTAINS(KWD, '"Man" AND NOT "Businessman"')

-- If search text is = woman,girl,-Working  the query will be
SELECT AS_ID FROM tbl_main
WHERE CONTAINS(KWD, '"woman" AND "girl" AND NOT "working"')
```

To search the multiple words (like the `mobile phone` in your case) use the quoted phrases:

```
SELECT AS_ID FROM tbl_main
WHERE CONTAINS(KWD, '"woman" AND "mobile phone"')
```

As commented below the quoted phrases are important in all searches to avoid bad searches in the case of e.g. when a search term is "tablet working" and the KWD value is `woman,girl,Digital Tablet,working,sitting,online`

There is a special case for a single `-` search term. The NOT cannot be used as the first term in the CONTAINS. Therefore, the query like this should be used:

```
-- If search text is = -Working  the query will be
SELECT AS_ID FROM tbl_main
WHERE NOT CONTAINS(KWD, '"working"')
```

Comment: In the case of record #6, `6   woman,girl,Digital Tablet,working,sitting,online`, if the input search was "tablet working", would this result in a match (ignoring the case of the input text)?

Comment: Yes Exactly !! agree with @CJBS

Comment: Use the quoted phrases then. I will update my answer

Comment: @cha yes!! we can manage the `- NOT`  in last of the search string

Comment: @cha THanks for the suggestion will let you know after its done :)

Comment: Please note that the CONTAINS has a [STOP LIST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx) The list contains some words that may be included in your column but be treated as noise words by SQL Servre. You should check it and configure

Comment: @cha Actually there's one more case to be aware of. If there's an entry with three words, e.g. `6 woman,girl,Digital Computer Tablet,working,sitting,online`, and "Digital Computer" was one of the search_text terms, this approach would produce a match. Now I could see that including the commas might be a way of handling this (e.g. `CONTAINS(KWD, '",Digital Computer,"')`, but this would still require all records to be updated with a preceding/trailing comma. Is there any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've described, you want the keywords that are included in the *search text* to be a match in the `KWD` column, and those that are prefixed with a `-` to be excluded.

Despite the data existing in this format, it still makes most sense to normalize the data, and then query based on the existence or non existence of the keywords.

To do this, in very rough terms:-

1. Create two additional tables - `Keyword` and `tbl_Main_Keyword`. `Keyword` contains a distinct list of each of the possible keywords and `tbl_Main_Keyword` contains a link between each record in `tbl_Main` to each `Keyword` record where there's a match. Ensure to create an index on the text field for the keyword (e.g. the `Keyword.KeywordText` column, or whatever you call it), as well as the `KeywordID` field in the `tbl_Main_Keyword` table. Create Foreign Keys between tables.
2. Write some [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) (or use a separate program, such as a C# program) to iterate through each record, parsing the text, and inserting each distinct keyword encountered into the `Keyword` table. Create a relationship to the row for each keyword in the `tbl_main` record.
3. Now, for searching, parse out the *search text* into keywords, and compose a query against the `tbl_Main_Keyword` table containing both a `WHERE KeywordID IN` and `WHERE KeywordID NOT IN` clause, depending on whether there is a match.

Take note to consider whether the case of each keyword is important to your business case, and consider the collation (case sensitive or insensitive) accordingly.

Comment: Is there any option that I can separate the serchtext in C# according to the condition `AND` or `Not` then Search it to SQL ??

Comment: I was suggesting using C# as an alternative to using TSQL/DML to do the one-off population of the new tables. It's possible to do this without using C#. As for the searching, the splitting of the terms can be done in or out of TSQL (it's not hard), but basically you're looking for matches in the joiner table:- one join or `WHERE IN` for each include/match term, and one for each exclude term.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer cha's solution, but here's another solution:

```
declare @QueryParts table (q varchar(1000))
insert into @QueryParts values
('woman'),
('girl'),
('-Working')

select AS_ID
from tbl_main
inner join @QueryParts on
(q not like '-%' and ',' + KWD + ',' like '%,' + q + ',%') or
(q like '-%' and ',' + KWD + ',' not like '%,' + substring(q, 2, 1000) + ',%')
group by AS_ID
having COUNT(*) = (select COUNT(*) from @QueryParts)
```

Answer (score 0):

With such a design, you would have two tables. One that defines the IDs and a subtable that holds the set of keywords per search string.

Likewise, you would transform the search strings into two tables, one for strings that should match and one for negated strings. Assuming that you put this in a stored procedure, these tables would be table-value parameters.

Once you have this set up, the query is simple to write:

```
SELECT M.AS_ID
FROM   tbl_main M
WHERE  (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   tbl_keywords K
        WHERE  K.AS_ID = M.AS_ID
          AND  K.KWD IN (SELECT word FROM @searchwords)) =
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @searchwords)
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   tbl_keywords K
                   WHERE  K.AS_ID = M.AS_ID
                     AND  K.KWD IN (SELECT word FROM @minuswords))
```