# Separate words by group wise for each row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string something like

```
No People,Day,side view,looking at camera,snow,mountain,tranquil scene,tranquility,Night,walking,water,Two Person,looking Down
```

And I have a table `Group_words`

```
Group                                                                                                                                                            Category
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------
No People,One Person,Two Person,Three Person,Four Person,five person,medium group of people,large group of people,unrecognizable person,real people              People
Day,dusk,night,dawn,sunset,sunrise                                                                                                                               Weather
looking at camera,looking way,looking sideways,looking down,looking up                                                                                           View Angle
```

I want to check every comma separated word with table `Group_words` and find the wrong combination.

For the above string result should be : "**No People,Day,side view,looking at camera,snow,mountain,tranquil scene,tranquility,walking,water**"

- `Night` is removed because `Day` is available in the string.
- `Two Person` is removed because `No People` is available in the string.
- `looking Down` is removed because `looking at camera` is available in the string.

I know its to complicated but simply I want to remove the not matching words from sting which is available into table `Group_words`.

Comment: And the mapping make sense as to which one to use and which to drop

Comment: How are they weighted

Comment: @DrewPierce Mapping is the word which is available into both the `sting` and `table `

Comment: Feel free to update your question with info such that it enables a solution

Comment: @DrewPierce Okay i'll update but my requirement is the same.

Comment: Great. It sounds like a nice challenging puzzle

Comment: @DrewPierce yeah!! for me too :(

Comment: `Two People` is removed because `No People` is available in the string -- but `Two People` is not included in the `People` category.

Comment: @wewesthemenace Sorry it was by mistake ...the correct is `Two  Person`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you should be re-designing your tables. Anyway, here is my attempt using Jeff Moden's [**DelimitedSplit8k**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

*I believe you now have this function since I answered one of your previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30973322/2203084) that also uses this function.*

First, you want to split your `@string` input into separate rows. You should also split the `Group_Words` table.

After that you do a `LEFT JOIN` to get the matching categories. Then you eliminate the invalid words.

See it in action here: [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6bb1/2/0)

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(8000)
SET @string = 'No People,Day,side view,looking at camera,snow,mountain,tranquil scene,tranquility,Night,walking,water,Two Person,looking Down'

-- Split @string variable
DECLARE @tbl_string AS TABLE(ItemNumber INT, Item VARCHAR(8000))
INSERT INTO @tbl_string
SELECT
    ItemNumber, LTRIM(RTRIM(Item))
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@string, ',')

-- Normalize Group_Words
DECLARE @tbl_grouping AS TABLE(Category VARCHAR(20), ItemNumber INT, Item VARCHAR(8000))
INSERT INTO @tbl_grouping
SELECT
    w.Category, s.ItemNumber, LTRIM(RTRIM(s.Item))
FROM Group_Words w
CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(w.[Group], ',')s

;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT      
        s.ItemNumber,
        s.Item,
        g.category,     
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.Category ORDER BY s.ItemNumber)
    FROM @tbl_string s
    LEFT JOIN @tbl_grouping g
        ON g.Item = s.Item
)
SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + Item
        FROM Cte
        WHERE 
            RN = 1
            OR Category IS NULL
        ORDER BY ItemNumber
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
    1, 1, '')
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
|                                                                                                  |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| No People,Day,side view,looking at camera,snow,mountain,tranquil scene,tranquility,walking,water |
```

---

If your `@string` input has more than `8000` characters, the `DelimitedSplit8K` will slow down. You can use other splitters instead. Here is one taken for Sir Aaron Bertrands's [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Comment: Sir you able to understand my query ... I'll let you know after using this  :) @wewesthemenace

Comment: Sir I am getting an error `String or binary data would be truncated.`

Comment: Try using `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead. But that'll probably slow down the split function.

Comment: Thanks Sir works perfect :) You are a genius (y) I want your fosterling :)

Comment: Thanks for the kind feedback. Now, you have to study this since you'll be the one supporting it. =)

Comment: good morning sir!! I have a question regarding the same query please let me know if you have a bit of time.

Comment: @Gitz, Could you post a new question for this?

Comment: But sir the question is same only select of the data is different