# Find the missing words

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am creating a module to find the missing words from the string in `SQL`

If I have a string

> "Man,one young men only,boat,adults only"

I want to match these words on the table `tbl_missingwords`.table is as following

```
ID  Keyword                 Synonym 
1   One young men only      young men,young adults,adults only
2   One young women only    young women,young adults,adults only
3   Domestic cat            Domestic animals,pats,animal themes
4   Domestic dog            Domestic animals,pats,animal themes
5   Adventure               recreation,persuit
6   Boat                    mode of transport,transport
```

Then the result should be

```
ID  Keyword                 Synonym 
1   One young men only      young men,young adults
6   Boat                    mode of transport,transport
```

Please help to select these missing words in `SQL`.

Comment: @Felix Pamittan  One more query for you.. please take a look on this question

Comment: Why is not `adults only ` included in the synonym for `ID = 1` in the result?

Comment: @Felix Pamittan Thanks for your replay....sir actually `adults only` is already used in the string that's why

Comment: Do you have any sql you have tried and did not work?

Comment: You are storing a multivaluated data in a single string. Split string in rows and do a single join. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings , http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Comment: This is a terrible design. If possible, you should remove the Synonym column and create a many-to-many relationship between the rows in tbl_missingwords.

Comment: I have a hard time following the logic here. Could you explain the logic in more detail? I can understand why "young men" is included in the expected outcome for id 1, but not why there is a difference between "young adults" and "adults only". They are both only partially matched with keyword, but still one is included and the other one not.

Comment: It's a key wording module sir @larsts

Comment: Both the database structure and the question itself are quite bad, both need a re-write to be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already asked a number of questions regarding this. Redesigning your table structures should now be your priority. Anyway, here is my solution using a splitter and `CROSS APPLY`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a5f5/2/0)

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Man,one young men only,boat,adults only'

DECLARE @tblStr AS TABLE(word VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @tblStr
    SELECT Item
    FROM dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@str, ',')

;WITH CteMissingWords(ID, Keyword, Synonym) AS(
    SELECT
        w.ID,
        w.Keyword,
        s.Item
    FROM tbl_missingwords w
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(w.Synonym, ',') s
)
SELECT
    tmw.ID, tmw.Keyword, x.Synonym
FROM tbl_missingwords tmw
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + cmw.Synonym
        FROM CteMissingWords cmw
        WHERE
            cmw.ID = tmw.ID
            AND cmw.Synonym NOT IN(SELECT word FROM @tblStr)
            AND cmw.Keyword IN(SELECT word FROM @tblStr)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
)x(Synonym)
WHERE x.Synonym IS NOT NULL
```

*The definition of `dbo.SplitStrings_XML` is already in [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31043151/2203084) of your previous question.*

Comment: Yes!! its working with the same function :) thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: And I will try to redesign the table structures

Answer (score 3):

First create a user-defined function to split the input string.

**Function - fn_split**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
   position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
BEGIN 
SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
  BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
      BREAK 
  END 
IF (@index > 1) 
  BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
    SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
  END 
ELSE
  SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
END
RETURN
END
```

Then try the following sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @str as varchar(max)

set @str='Man,one young men only,boat,adults only'

select ID,min(keyword) as keyword,
case when right(min([Synonym]),1) = ','
then replace(left(min([Synonym]),len(min([Synonym]))-1),',,',',')
else replace(min([Synonym]),',,',',') end as [Synonym]
from
(
    select ID,Keyword,value,replace([Synonym],Value,'') as [Synonym]
    from fn_split(@str,','),
    tbl_missingwords
    where Keyword in (select value from fn_split(@str,','))
)t
group by ID;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31fe5/2)

Comment: Okay sir i am trying ..will let you know

Comment: Is this functions work with case sensitive words ?? @Ullas

Comment: its not case-sensitive.